# Extend the customer entity in Sitecore commerce

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am working in Sitecore Commerce 10. I have added new Property to the **Customer entity** as **DOB** using the **Composer template**. How to make this field editable on the Profile Editor storefront page?
Thanks in advance.